# Bad approximation, alternative definiton

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I read Complex dynamics of Carleson and Gamelin. They state without a proof the following

$\theta$ is called bad approximate if there exists  $c>0$ and $\mu<\infty$ such that $$ \Big\vert \theta - \frac{p}{q}\Big \vert  > \frac{c}{q^{\mu}}$$
for all integer $p$ and $q$ ( $ q \neq 0$). This is supposedly only occures if and only if:

$\lambda = e^{2\pi i \theta}$ satisfying 
$$ \Big \vert \lambda^n -1 \Big \vert > c n^{1-\mu} , \quad  \forall n\geq 1$$
For some $c>0$ and $\mu<\infty$

I can not se any way to prove this statement, grateful for help.

Comment: Did you mean $\forall n \geq 1$? Also, is the thing you want to show equivalence to the statement that (for some given bad approximale $\theta$) for any n ($\geq 1 ?$) there exist $c$ and $\mu$ such that $|\lambda^n-1|>cn^{1-\mu}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is along the lines of what you're looking for, but I thought I'd give it a shot anyway. We have the exponential map
\begin{align*}
\exp : \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{T},\\
\left[x \right] &\longmapsto e^{2 \pi i x}
\end{align*}
from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to the (complex) unit circle. The topology on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is induced by the following metric: For $\left[ x \right], \left[ y \right] \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, 
\begin{align*}
d_1 ( \left[ x \right], \left[ y \right] ) = \min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-k\cdot y|.
\end{align*}
The topology on $\mathbb{T}$ is induced by the metric 
\begin{align*}
d_2 ( e^{2 \pi i x}, e^{2 \pi i y} ) = \text{length of the shortest path on $\mathbb{T}$ from $e^{2 \pi i x}$ to $e^{2 \pi i y}$}.
\end{align*}
These metrics are related in the following way: $2 \pi \cdot d_1 (\left[x \right], \left[ y \right]) = d_2 (\exp (x), \exp (y))$.

Now, if there is $c > 0$ and $\mu \geqslant 1$ such that $| \theta - p/q | > c/q^{\mu}$ for all $p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then for any fixed integer $p$, $|n \theta - p | > c/n^{\mu - 1}$ for all $n \geqslant 1$. This implies that
\begin{align*}
d_1 (\left[ p \right], \left[n \theta \right]) > \frac{c}{n^{\mu - 1}},
\end{align*}
which implies that
\begin{align*}
d_2 ( \exp (p), \exp(n \theta)) = d_2 (1, e^{2 \pi i n \theta}) > \frac{2 \pi c}{n^{\mu - 1}}.
\end{align*}
So the shortest arc from $1$ to $e^{2 \pi i n \theta}$ has length at least $2 \pi c / n^{\mu - 1}$. But since
\begin{align*}
\text{chordal length} \geqslant \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \text{arc length},
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
|e^{2 \pi i n \theta} - 1| > \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{2 \pi c}{n^{\mu - 1}} = \frac{4c}{n^{\mu - 1}}.
\end{align*}
It is also possible to prove the other direction this way, although possibly with a smaller $c$. But that shouldn't matter since being badly approximable just means that there is *some* $c > 0$ such that the relevant inequality is satisfied.

Comment: I have edited the question, but i think this should to it! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have thought a bit and think i have solved one direction myself. The proof is based on proving following inequality.

$$ \vert \lambda^n -1 \vert=\vert e^{2\pi i n \theta}-1\vert  < 2 \pi \vert \theta n -p\vert,\quad  \forall p,n \in \mathbb{Z}$$.

We have

$$
\begin{align}
\vert e^{2 \pi i n \theta}-1 \vert& = \vert e^{\pi i n\theta}\vert \vert e^{2 \pi i n \theta}-1 \vert\\
& = \vert e^{ \pi i n \theta}- e^{-\pi i n \theta} \vert \\
& =2 \vert \frac{e^{ \pi i n \theta}- e^{-\pi i n \theta}}{2i} \vert \\
& = 2 \vert\sin{\pi n\theta}\vert \\
& = \{\vert \sin{x}\vert \text{ is } \pi\text{-periodic}\}\\
& = 2 \vert \sin{\pi n \theta - \pi p}\vert\\
& = \{ \text{ Use that } \vert \sin{x}\vert \leq \vert x \vert \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \}\\
& = 2\vert \pi (n\theta -p)\vert\\
& = 2\pi\vert n \theta -p\vert
\end{align}
$$

So given this inequality we can first prove the first direction. Assume  $\theta$ is not bad approximal. Then for all $c>0$ and $ \mu < \infty$ we have some $p\in \mathbb{Z},q\in \mathbb{Z}^*$ such that

$$\vert \theta - \frac{p}{q}\vert < \frac{c}{q^{\mu}}$$

But then we have that

$$
\begin{align}
\vert \lambda^n-1 \vert & < 2 \pi \vert n \theta -p\vert\\
& = 2\pi n\vert \theta -\frac{p}{n}\vert\\
& < 2 \pi n \frac{c}{n^{\mu }}\\
& = 2 \pi cn^{1-\mu}
\end{align}
$$

For the converse i can not see if one can apply the same metod.